# Using Excel VBA, How do I limit the results of a query using ADODB.connection & ADODB.Recordset?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

After some time and lots of help from stackOverflow users and Christos Samaras Tutorial on [Running Access Queries From Excel Using VBA] (https://myengineeringworld.net/2013/10/running-access-queries-from-excel-vba.html), I got most of what I need in terms of getting data from Access using a parameter.

Here's my problem, I would like to enter the parameter using an InputBox.  For some reason, it keeps telling me that the recordset was not created. Then the function exits and nothing happened.

I've tried to use different versions of setting up the strSQL string, but each time I get further away from it working.

Again, the first code does work, but I'm having a hard time implementing something that would ask for a parameter.

'''THIS CODE WORKS'''

```
Public Function ProjLookup(ProjID As String) As Boolean

Dim INV_WB As Workbook
Dim ProjSet As Worksheet
Dim CovPage As Worksheet
Dim DataConnect As Object
Dim RecordSet As Object
Dim strTable As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim i As Integer

Set INV_WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ProjSet = INV_WB.Worksheets("ProjectSetup")
Set CovPage = INV_WB.Worksheets("CoverPage")

'---> Establish connection
On Error Resume Next
    Set DataConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
       If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       MsgBox "Connection was not created", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
            Exit Function
        End If
On Error GoTo 0

'---> Open connection with Project Details database
DataConnect.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\CTR90947\OneDrive - PAE\Database\Project Details.accdb"


 '---->I would like to enter 601130 into an InputBox                        
    strSQL = "SELECT [Level_1_ProjID], [Legacy_Lvl1_Proj], [ProjectID], [Legacy_ProjID], [Level_Number], [Project_Name] FROM qr_Map_ProjSetupDetail WHERE [Level_1_ProjID] = '601130'"

 'Create Recordset    
Set RecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set RecordSet = Nothing
    Set DataConnect = Nothing
    MsgBox "Recordset was not created", vbCritical, "Recordset Error"
End If

RecordSet.CursorLocation = 3
RecordSet.CursorType = 1

'Open Recordset using strSQL
RecordSet.Open strSQL, DataConnect

If RecordSet.EOF And RecordSet.BOF Then
    RecordSet.Close
    DataConnect.Close

    Set RecordSet = Nothing
    Set DataConnect = Nothing

    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset", vbCritical, "No Records Found"

    Exit Function
End If

'---> Enter names into columns in ProjectSetup worksheet
For i = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
    ProjSet.Cells(5, i + 1) = RecordSet.Fields(i).Name
Next i

'---> Populate ProjectSetup worksheet using recordset results
ProjSet.Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet

RecordSet.Close
DataConnect.Close

MsgBox "Project Setup Query complete!"

End Function
```

'''THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK'''

```
Public Function ProjLookupWithInputBox(ProjID As String) As Boolean

Dim INV_WB As Workbook
Dim ProjSet As Worksheet
Dim CovPage As Worksheet
Dim LVL1_GLPROD_ID As String
Dim DataConnect As Object
Dim RecordSet As Object
Dim strTable As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim i As Integer

Set INV_WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set ProjSet = INV_WB.Worksheets("ProjectSetup")
Set CovPage = INV_WB.Worksheets("CoverPage")


On Error Resume Next
    Set DataConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Connection was not created", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
            Exit Function
        End If
On Error GoTo 0


DataConnect.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\CTR90947\OneDrive - PAE\Database\Project Details.accdb"

    LVL1_GLPROD_ID = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter 6 Digit GLPRD Project ID", Title:="Project ID Input Box", Default:="Type Here")
    strSQL = "SELECT [Level_1_ProjID], [Legacy_Lvl1_Proj], [ProjectID], [Legacy_ProjID], [Level_Number], [Project_Name] FROM qr_Map_ProjSetupDetail WHERE [Level_1_ProjID] = 'LVL1_GLPROD_ID'"

Set RecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set RecordSet = Nothing
    Set DataConnect = Nothing
    MsgBox "Recordset was not created", vbCritical, "Recordset Error"
End If

RecordSet.CursorLocation = 3
RecordSet.CursorType = 1

RecordSet.Open strSQL, DataConnect

If RecordSet.EOF And RecordSet.BOF Then
    RecordSet.Close
    DataConnect.Close

    Set RecordSet = Nothing
    Set DataConnect = Nothing

    MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset", vbCritical, "No Records Found"

    Exit Function
End If



For i = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
    ProjSet.Cells(5, i + 1) = RecordSet.Fields(i).Name
Next i

ProjSet.Range("A6").CopyFromRecordset RecordSet

RecordSet.Close
DataConnect.Close

MsgBox "Project Setup Query complete!"

End Function
```

When I walk through the code and watch the progress through the Locals screen, everything seems to work fine until I step through the 'RecordSet.Open strSQL, DataConnect' line.  Not sure why no records are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code that doesnt work has the variable within the string literal - the variable cannot be referenced this way. It has to be

```
     LVL1_GLPROD_ID = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter 6 Digit GLPRD Project ID", Title:="Project ID Input Box", Default:="Type Here")
     strSQL = "SELECT [Level_1_ProjID], [Legacy_Lvl1_Proj], [ProjectID], [Legacy_ProjID], [Level_Number], [Project_Name] FROM qr_Map_ProjSetupDetail WHERE [Level_1_ProjID] = '" & LVL1_GLPROD_ID & "'"
```

More technical nonsense:

the real reason it doesnt work is there is no value in the column "[Level_1_ProjID]" that equals "LVL1_GLPROD_ID"

i also did some light rewrite for you:

```
Public Function ProjLookupWithInputBox(ProjID As String) As Boolean
    Dim INV_WB As Workbook
    Dim LVL1_GLPROD_ID As String, strTable As String, strSQL As String
    Dim DataConnect As Object, rs As Object     'also naming objects after reserved words is dumb.
    Dim i As long   'i dont use integer often, because sometimes you unintentionally get past the upperbound of the data type. Plus int in SQL Server = long in vba

    Set INV_WB = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next    'i hate this
    Set DataConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Connection was not created", vbCritical, "Connection Error"
        Exit Function
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0         ' i also hate this

    DataConnect.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\CTR90947\OneDrive - PAE\Database\Project Details.accdb"
    LVL1_GLPROD_ID = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter 6 Digit GLPRD Project ID", Title:="Project ID Input Box", Default:="Type Here")
    strSQL = "SELECT [Level_1_ProjID], [Legacy_Lvl1_Proj], [ProjectID], [Legacy_ProjID], [Level_Number], [Project_Name] FROM qr_Map_ProjSetupDetail WHERE [Level_1_ProjID] ='" & LVL1_GLPROD_ID & "';"

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set DataConnect = Nothing
        MsgBox "rs was not created", vbCritical, "rs Error"
    End If

    rs.CursorLocation = 3
    rs.CursorType = 1
    rs.Open strSQL, DataConnect

    If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
        rs.Close
        DataConnect.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set DataConnect = Nothing
        MsgBox "There are no records in the recordset", vbCritical, "No Records Found"
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        INV_WB.Worksheets("ProjectSetup").Cells(5, i + 1) = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    INV_WB.Worksheets("ProjectSetup").Range("A6").CopyFromRecordSet rs
    rs.Close
    DataConnect.Close
    MsgBox "Project Setup Query complete!"
End Function
```