# What are the limits of ADODB in Excel - Odd results

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

Long time lurker, first time poster.
THANKS for all the previous help - MOST APPRECIATED and I've learned A LOT!

I have an Excel worksheet with 107,141 records.
For reference, I'm using the basic code from this page:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701533/using-excel-vba-how-do-i-limit-the-results-of-a-query-using-adodb-connection](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
Public Function RecordSetFromSheet(sheetName As String)

Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnx As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

    'setup the connection
    '[HDR=Yes] means the Field names are in the first row
    With cnx
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "'; " & "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"
        .Open
    End With

    str_SQL = "SELECT * From [" & sheetName & "$]" & _
        "WHERE [Profession] = 'Veterinary Medicine' " & _
        "AND [Type] = 'Veterinarian' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Cln Ac Ltd' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Ed Ltd' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Nonaprv Prgm Ltd' " & _
        "AND [County] = 'Livingston' Or [County] = 'Macomb' Or [County] = 'Monroe' Or [County] = 'Oakland' Or [County] = 'Washtenaw' Or [County] = 'Wayne'"

    'setup the command
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnx
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
'    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetName & "$]"
    cmd.CommandText = str_SQL
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rst.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    rst.LockType = adLockOptimistic

    'open the connection
    rst.Open cmd

    'disconnect the recordset
    Set rst.ActiveConnection = Nothing

    'cleanup
    If CBool(cmd.State And adStateOpen) = True Then
        Set cmd = Nothing
    End If

    If CBool(cnx.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnx.Close
    Set cnx = Nothing

    '"return" the recordset object
    Set RecordSetFromSheet = rst

End Function

Public Sub Test()

Dim rstData As ADODB.Recordset
Set rstData = RecordSetFromSheet("Sheet2")

rstData.MoveFirst
rstData.MoveLast
MsgBox rstData.RecordCount

rstData.Filter = "County = 'Macomb'"

rstData.MoveFirst
rstData.MoveLast
MsgBox rstData.RecordCount

rstData.Close
Set rstData = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have no errors creating the objects and the recordset.

However, as *bad* luck would have it, the records I need (at least initially) are all towards the bottom on the data.

I describe it as bad luck because when I use the SQL of:
`str_SQL = "SELECT * From [" & sheetName & "$]"`
I only get the upper 41,604 records.

Are there some built-in limitations with ADODB?
Is this a System Resource limitation?
If so, without adding more memory, are there any settings I can apply to get all (or at least more) records?

But wait, there's more...

In order to perform more testing and hopefully make this work out, I copied the bottom 14,592 records to a different sheet (*and also updated the sheet name reference in the code*).
Now when I re-run the above SQL I get the proper record count, 14,592.
But I need to further narrow down the records so I add more SQL as follows:

```
str_SQL = "SELECT * From [" & sheetName & "$]" & _
"WHERE [Profession] = 'Veterinary Medicine' " & _
"AND [Type] = 'Veterinarian' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Cln Ac Ltd' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Ed Ltd' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Nonaprv Prgm Ltd'"
```

Actually, to save space here, technically I first added the initial `WHERE` clause and when that record count was correct I added the following `AND` clause.
This query returns the correct number of records, *4,584*.

But here's where things get weird again...
If I run the SQL below:

```
str_SQL = "SELECT * From [" & sheetName & "$]" & _
"WHERE [Profession] = 'Veterinary Medicine' " & _
"AND [Type] = 'Veterinarian' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Cln Ac Ltd' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Ed Ltd' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Nonaprv Prgm Ltd' " & _
"AND [County] = 'Livingston' Or [County] = 'Macomb' Or [County] = 'Monroe' Or [County] = 'Oakland' Or [County] = 'Washtenaw' Or [County] = 'Wayne'"
```

I get *8,741* records!!!

As a further test, if I use the below line on the resulting recordset:
`rstData.Filter = "County = 'Macomb'"`
I get 1,099 records instead of the correct record count of 184.
However, it's evident the `.Filter` is filtering the recordset albeit not to the correct record count.
Most likely, the `.Filter` is resulting in the wrong record count because the initial recordset has way too many records. I know this to be true because if I use the filter `rstData.Filter = "County = 'Macomb'"` on the *last *SQL incarnation that has the c*orrect number of records*, the filter results in 184 records as expected.

But what's going on with that last SQL?
How is the resulting recordset getting *more *records than the SQL that doesn't include the last `AND` clause?
Is there something wrong with my SQL or am I missing something important?
[scratching head begins]
Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: What version of Windows/Office do you have ?

Comment: Windows 10 with Office 2013 x64

Comment: And it works with `.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"`,`Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1` ? Try `.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" ` and `Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro etc` . Is is an xlsm file ?

Comment: XLSB.
I prefer binary files.

Comment: That's odd.
I copied the code from the other referenced page and didn't even notice the older Jet and Excel versions.

I have the reference Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library checked.
I tried the edits you suggested and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the Jet vs. ACE.  As it turns out, that was the cause of the initial limitation on the records being pulled from the worksheet.
All my issues are now resolved.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When mixing AND and OR in SQL you really need parentheses to make sure the logic is doing what you expect....

```sql
...AND A or B or c
   AND C or D or E
```

should probably be

```sql
...AND (A or B or c)
   AND (C or D or E)
```

This (for example):

```sql
AND [County] = 'Livingston' Or [County] = 'Macomb' Or [County] = 'Monroe' Or [County] = 'Oakland' Or [County] = 'Washtenaw' Or [County] = 'Wayne'"
```

could also be written as:

```sql
AND [County] IN ('Livingston','Macomb','Monroe','Oakland','Washtenaw', 'Wayne')
```

...which can also help resolve the AND/OR issue.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and something still must be very wrong.

This SQL only gets 4 records:
`    str_SQL = "SELECT * From [" & sheetName & "$]" & _
        "WHERE (([Profession] = 'Veterinary Medicine') " & _
        "AND ([Type] = 'Veerinarian' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Cln Ac Ltd' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Ed Ltd' Or [Type] = 'Veterinarian Nonaprv Prgm Ltd') " & _
        "AND ([County] = 'Livingston' Or [County] = 'Macomb' Or [County] = 'Monroe' Or [County] = 'Oakland' Or [County] = 'Washtenaw' Or [County] = 'Wayne'))"
`

Comment: I'll try your second suggestion now...

Comment: `[Type] = 'Veerinarian' `  typo?

Comment: wow.
That was it.

Sometimes if seems like if I'm not fat-fingering the keyboard I'm light fingering it.

While I have you though, I have more I need to add to the query.

Comment: There are two fields I need to filter out records with blank cells in two columns.
Since this is in Excel, not in a proper database, I'm assuming there is no use of null so how do I do this in Excel ADODB?

`"AND [Email] >""`

`"AND [First Name] >""`

Comment: `        "AND ([First Name] > '') " & _
        "AND ([Email] > ''))"
`
Works perfectly.
Correct record count now.
THANKS!

Comment: Thanks for the assist.
The typo was the issue.
I've added the last two AND sections and they work too.

But what about the first part of my question?
Why am I only able to see the first 41,604 records in the worksheet?
In oder for my query to even have any records upon which to work, I have to first copy the bottom ~40K records over to a different worksheet.

Comment: 100k-40k =~ 60k, which was close to the old row limit for Excel, so maybe try using one of the newer drivers suggested in the comments above.  What file type are you using to store your data?

Comment: Wow.
It's a good thing it wasn't a poisonous snake or I'd be dead by now.
I actually had already updated the provider to Ace, etc. but didn't think (know) to check the initial record count.
Now it pulls all the <107K records so the query now works perfectly without any need to copy data to another worksheet first.
THANKS TO ALL

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out.